# What does this make me?

Tags: riddle, word

> Technically I am just a process, a journey the philosopher may say.
>   Nothing can contain me.
>   For men may come and men may go, I go on forever<sup>1</sup>
>   Take what you want or give what you want I remain just the same.
>   I have an opposite and it's not death.

What does this make me?

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>*(Taken from the poem "The Brook")*</sub>

Edit:- Edited the question to reduce the number of possible answers. Please let me know if I should edit anything else.

Comment: Please do have a single answer in mind, or else your question could be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'm new here. Will edit it in a jiffy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be the

> infinity.

Technically I am just a process, a journey the philosopher may say.

> Could refer to Zeno's paradoxes, most likely the one about Achilles and the Tortoise. Zeno is credited with introduction of the mathematical infinity.

Nothing can contain me.

> It's infinite.

For men may come and men may go, I go on forever

> The poem may refer to infinite cycle of life

Take what you want or give what you want I remain just the same.

> Substract or add any finite number to infinity and you will still get the infinity.

Comment: Technically, ∞ - 1 =/= ∞. Yes, you cannot measure it, and ∞ - 1 ≈ ∞, but it is not the same.

Comment: Actually, in calculus it is.

Comment: The answer I was looking for. It is a counting process. (keep adding one to the largest number you can think of).

Answer (score 5):

May be Answer is

> Time

Technically I am just a process, a journey the philosopher may say

> TEchnically Time is just a process, and also journey.

Nothing can contain me.

> Nothing can hold time

For men may come and men may go, I go on forever

> Time running, whoever go or gone

Take what you want, I remain just the same

> No one can change the time

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the question?. I strictly didn't want this as an answer. I forgot to include it while posting the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking lol

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal what's wrong with it though? it seems acceptable

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer at all. It is very easy to guess and I didn't want people's attention to go towards this.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal well the question is relatively broad.

Comment: Yes. I goofed up. I forgot to include these conditions. Had them in mind, will be careful next time.

Answer (score 3):

How about

> LIFE?

*Technically I am just a process, a journey the philosopher may say.*

> We journey through life, and a lifetime can be seen as a process.

*Nothing can contain me.*

> You can't contain life, shut it up in a box: it can't be imprisoned or priced.

*For men may come and men may go, I go on forever*

> Individual people come and go, but life itself goes on regardless.

*Take what you want or give what you want I remain just the same.*

> No matter what we give and take in life, it still continues on.

Comment: Acceptable answer but not what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be:

> Learning.

Technically I'm just a process, a journey the philosopher would say

> Learning IS a process, and the 'philosopher' bit may be of added significance.

Nothing can contain me

> Learning has no boundaries.

For men may come and men may go, I go on forever

> Many great thinkers come and go, only adding to the pool of things to be learned.

Take what you want or give what you want I remain just the same.

> You can take away any lesson or give any insight, but the act of learning remains much the same across generations.

Comment: Although I think this is a good answer, I want to point out that through time, people learn in different ways, and at some points in time, some people couldn't learn.

Comment: Nice perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> Thinking  / Imagination

Technically I am just a process, a journey the philosopher may say.

> That's all philosophers do...think and imagine. They produce nothing. :)

Nothing can contain me.

> There is a saying that there is no limit to the imagination or thought.  (Except imagining a new color).

For men may come and men may go, I go on forever (Taken from the poem "The Brook")

> Ideas can be passed from person to person and even when someone dies their thought can be continued by someone else.

You cannot see me. Yet you discuss and try to comprehend me.

> Obviously you cannot see the imagination (unless you are on drugs or something) and the human brain (part of it at least) is still a puzzle for scientists.

Take what you want, I remain just the same.

> There is no specific amount of thoughts or imagination.

Comment: Awesome. It needn't necessarily go on forever. They can be abandoned before being passed on :)

Comment: Agree..But it still can go on forever.

Comment: It can be "gone" if all the people are gone and there is noone to keep it alive, so it is not strictly speaking "forever"

Comment: A nice answer nevertheless. I never expected this answer. Thought quite a lot about it before posting this riddle here.